# Zeros of $f(x)=x^3-x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, roots

Zeros of the $f(x)=x^3-x$ are $x=-1, x=1$   and $x=0$. We can compute it by solving this equation :

$x^3-x=0$

$x^2=1$

$x=1$ and $-1$
But when we divide both part of equation by x , we say that $x$ is not $0$. On the other hand $f(0)$ is defined.

What do I miss?

Comment: It isn't that we are assuming $x \ne 0$, it is that we are saying "if $x \ne 0$ then $x = 1$ or $x = -1$".  You still have to consider the $x = 0$ case.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot divide by $x$ unless you know $x \neq 0$.

The equation $x^2 = 1$ is not equivalent to the equation $x^3 - x = 0$.  You obtained the equation $x^3 - x = 0$ by adding $x$ to both sides of the equation, then dividing by $x$.  However, you can only divide by $x$ if $x \neq 0$.  Therefore, when you divided by $x$, you implicitly assumed that $x \neq 0$, which is why you lost the solution $x = 0$.

We can solve the equation by factoring the cubic and setting each factor equal to zero.

\begin{align*}
x^3 - x & = 0\\
x(x^2 - 1) & = 0\\
x(x + 1)(x - 1) & = 0
\end{align*}

Setting each factor equal to zero yields
\begin{align*}
x & = 0 & x + 1 & = 0 & x - 1 & = 0\\
  & & x & = -1 & x & = 1
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

To follow your division-by-$x$ path, note that the complete argument might look as follows:

Let $x$ be a real number satisfying
$$\tag1x^3-x=0.$$
There are two cases:

- $x=0$: We verify immediately that $0^3-0=0$, so $x=0$ is a possible solution.$^1$
- $x\ne 0$: In this case, we may divide both sides of the equation by $x$ and obtain the equivalent$^2$ (as long as $x\ne0$) equation
  $$x^2-1=0 $$
  with the two solutions $x=1$ and $x=-1$.  (fortunately, none of these is $0$, so they are both valid)$^3$.

In summary: $x$ satisfies $(1)$ if and only if $x=0$ or $x=1$ or $x=-1$.

---

$^1$  In a more general situation, it might have happend that a specifically considered special case is *not* a solution! One *must* check it!

$^2$ In a more general situation, we might have performed some transforms that are not equivalances. In that case, we would need to check the found "solutions", preferably against the original equation.

$^3$ In a more general situation, the produced equation *might* have solutions that are excluded as per the case premise; these must be ignored here and are to be found in the other case explicitly allowing this value.

Comment: I would also observe that this is the reason one should avoid "dividing by $x$", as in:
\begin{align}
&x^3 - x = 0\\
\implies &x^3 = x\\
\implies &x^2 = 0 
\end{align}
since not only does it "miss" possible roots, it may also lead to paradoxes, such as $1$ being a root of the equation of the first line, but not of the last line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider x = 0 case.
The best way to solve this one is:
$$x^3-x=0$$
$$x(x^2-1)=0$$
You have 2 cases:
$$x = 0$$
$$x^2-1 = 0 \implies x= \pm1$$